# Wordpress JS Reference Error on a var

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming, referenceerror

So I am fairly new to Wordpress theming. I know that wordpress can misunderstand certain Jquery $ code and that you should use jQuery(document).ready(function($) {} instead of just plain $(.) code. 
*Note: The JS files have been properly registered and enqueue'd, they all show up in source.

My problem is that I have a custom.js file that lists some custom JS and Jquery code for my theme. Without wordpress it works fine. However, with wordpress it is breaking.

Here is the code:

```
//sticky header on scroll
jQuery(window).load(function() {
jQuery(".sticky").sticky({topSpacing: 0});
});

//parallax
jQuery(window).stellar({
    horizontalScrolling: false,
    responsive: true/*,
     scrollProperty: 'scroll',
     parallaxElements: false,
     horizontalScrolling: false,
     horizontalOffset: 0,
     verticalOffset: 0*/
});

/*====flex  slider for main slider on header2====*/
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.main-slider').flexslider({
    slideshowSpeed: 5000,
    directionNav: false,
    controlNav: true,
    animation: "fade"
})
});

//owl carousel for work
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#work-carousel").owlCarousel({
        // Most important owl features
        items: 4,
        itemsCustom: false,
        itemsDesktop: [1199, 4],
        itemsDesktopSmall: [980, 3],
        itemsTablet: [768, 3],
        itemsTabletSmall: false,
        itemsMobile: [479, 1],
        singleItem: false,
        startDragging: true
    });

});

//owl carousel for testimonials
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

 jQuery("#testi-carousel").owlCarousel({
        // Most important owl features
        items: 1,
        itemsCustom: false,
        itemsDesktop: [1199, 1],
        itemsDesktopSmall: [980, 1],
        itemsTablet: [768, 1],
        itemsTabletSmall: false,
        itemsMobile: [479, 1],
        singleItem: false,
        startDragging: true
    });

});
//owl carousel for full width image slider
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#full-img-slide").owlCarousel({
        // Most important owl features
        items: 1,
        itemsCustom: false,
        itemsDesktop: [1199, 1],
        itemsDesktopSmall: [980, 1],
        itemsTablet: [768, 1],
        itemsTabletSmall: false,
        itemsMobile: [479, 1],
        singleItem: false,
        startDragging: true
    });

});

/* ==============================================
 Counter Up
 =============================================== */
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('.counter').counterUp({
        delay: 100,
        time: 800
    });
});


/* ==============================================
 WOW plugin triggers animate.css on scroll
 =============================================== */

var wow = new WOW(
        {
            boxClass: 'wow', // animated element css class (default is wow)
            animateClass: 'animated', // animation css class (default is animated)
            offset: 100, // distance to the element when triggering the animation (default is 0)
            mobile: false        // trigger animations on mobile devices (true is default)
        }
);
wow.init();

//portfolio mix
jQuery('#grid').mixitup();


/*========tooltip and popovers====*/
/*==========================*/
jQuery("[data-toggle=popover]").popover();

jQuery("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip();
```

I am getting an error on console with Uncaught ReferenceError: WOW is not defined for the following lines:

```
var wow = new WOW(
        {
            boxClass: 'wow', // animated element css class (default is wow)
            animateClass: 'animated', // animation css class (default is animated)
            offset: 100, // distance to the element when triggering the animation (default is 0)
            mobile: false        // trigger animations on mobile devices (true is default)
        }
);
wow.init();
```

I am not sure how to fix this, as I guess it is saying that WOW is an undefined variable. WOW is in reference to the wow.js library (https://github.com/matthieua/WOW) and is using their javascript to call it on the homepage.

If you can help it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this fixes the problem here. It worked for me!

```
 jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    wow = new WOW(
        {
            boxClass:     'wow',      
            animateClass: 'animated', 
            offset:       100,         
            mobile:       false,     
            live:         true       
        }
    )
    wow.init();
});
```

note: wrap it inside document ready

Answer (score 0):

In your functions.php in wordpress, did you wp_enqueue_script() or wp_register_script() for wow.js?

Wordpress Codex says "This is the recommended method of linking JavaScript to a WordPress generated page."

[Check it out](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script-and-styles-in-wordpress/) in the wp codex. Or, you can read [what wpbeginner.com has to say](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-add-javascripts-and-styles-in-wordpress/) on this topic ;)

Comment: Hi yes, I did wp_register and wp_enqueue the wow.js and it is loading onto the site, as is all other js files needed. The problem has to do with the way the var wow is changing to the new wow i believe. It is considering it undefined. Again, the code works outside of wordpress.

Comment: Shouldn't your new WOW wait until document ready? Looks like it's being called before wow.js is loaded, hence it being undefined. Any reason leaving your new WOW object to be defined before document.ready()?